# Intellij idea Robot Framework keywords

Tags: intellij-idea, robotframework

Screen capture of my Intellij IDEA shows problem. My own keywords are ok, but Robot Framework keywords are all underlined with red color. Not good.

[image]

I'm using Intellij IDEA to develop Robot Framework test cases using Selenium Library. My IDEA is recognizing all Keyword that I have implemented, but doesn't recognize any library Keywords. It is underlining those with red color and doesn't suggest or give any hints for those. Here is version information about my IDEA:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5

Do you have any suggestions? What should I check from my IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I stumbled upon this during my research for the same problem, so here is my result.

In the description of the [Robot Framework Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7415-robot-framework-support) for IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm is stated that the support for library keywords is only with the help of either PyCharm or the [Python plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python). But unfortunately, that is only available for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition. There is a version for [the Community edition](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7322-python-community-edition), but it's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported Selenium Library under Settings. It doesn't come automatically like the BuiltIn keywords.

Also, make sure you are importing the right version of Selenium. There's SeleniumLibrary, Selenium2Library, and Selenium2LibraryExtended.

The only reason I'm suggesting this is because you didn't share your Settings code, which would give me a better picture of what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brandon. 

I get tired of IntelliJ IDEA and started to use PyCharm. That is working nicely and I don't have this problem there. Only thing I need to do is import Selenium2Library (as you mentioned), but that I had all ready done in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Good call on using PyCharm, I prefer that one and I've never had a problem with it. Another possibility is that you needed to declare Selenium2Library as a Resource, not a Library (despite the name). As a side note, if you're using a separate page for your custom keywords, you can import Selenium2Library there and it'll be available for use in your main .robot file.

Comment: Jep. I have quite a large system and lot of .robot files there. I'm using different kind of resource-files heavily. With PyCharm everything seems to work smoothly. Some restarts of PyCharm are needed sometimes.